# How can I limit the output of a command that does not have newlines?

Tags: linux, shell

How can I limit the output of a command that does not have newlines? In other words, the output is one very long line.

Comment: Post sample input and desired output.

Comment: Sample input and output can be arbitrary. Let's say the original output is m characters long. I would like to reduce it n characters long, where n < m

Comment: Do you want the n characters from the beginning of output, from the end of output, or from somewhere in the middle? If from the middle, how do you recognize the "correct" bit of output?

Answer (score 1):

Use `cut -b` as following:

```
printf '%s' 'very long line .....' |cut -b -10
```

this cuts the first 10bytes of the line; you may want to use `-c` if you want characters instead of bytes.

by design `cut` adds the newline to its output (it's can be removed by passing to some other tools), but you might want to use `head -c 10` instead as an alternative.